# Android XML, Activity Edit Text

Tags: java, android, xml, android-activity

Android XML, Activity Edit Text. i have EditText in XML and tried to define the Edit text in LaunchActivity.java But the android studio is not showing me EditText in intellisense

[image]

Comment: Please post code as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MyAss if your intellisense doesnt show up try rebuilding the project or

> import it manually like this

```
import android.widget.EditText;
```

Comment: Great thing i did manually and i am getting it.. thank you brother

Comment: if it worked please feel free to update the answer please @RakeshRavindraPatige

Comment: Update my answer.. can please tell me how to do it. i am new to this

Answer (score 1):

> try importing in LaunchActivity.java manually as shown below -

```
import android.widget.EditText;
```

Comment: Wonderful if the solution reached

Answer (score 0):

If the intellisense would not show the function, then try to import libraries manually.
the answer for my question was

import android.widget.EditText;

Answer (score 0):

try this solutions

1. Go File > Invalidate Caches / Restart... > Click at Invalidate and Restart
2. You can also check if Power Save Modeon File menu is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings (Ctrl + Alt + s) and type "exclude import". Now in the "Auto Import" tab check to see if you have any rows in the "Exclude from Import and Completion" area. If yes, then delete all the rows there. And now, in your dropdown import list you can select the right import for your code.[image]